# Can you redirect exception handling to URLs in ASP.NET?

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, exception, routes, middleware

**I'm working on a ASP.NET Core application with ReactJS and I'd like unhandled exceptions to have their data redirected to a particular route (URL to a React Component).** For instance, suppose I have a controller as follows:

```cs
public class StartProblemsController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get()
    {
        int a = 1;
        int b = 0;
        int err = a / b;

        return Ok();
    }
}
```

This clearly throws an `DivideByZero` exception at runtime when routed to. However, the exception is only displayed in the console and the front-end silently fails by displaying me a blank web page. I've got the following middleware:

```cs
app.UseExceptionHandler("/error");
app.UseHsts();
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
        name: "default",
        pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});

app.UseSpa(spa =>
{
    spa.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});
```

I would think that `app.UseExceptionHandler("/error")` would do the trick and would redirect the browser to `https://.../error` but it doesn't. It remains at `https://.../startproblems`. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

React runs through npm, server routing will be overwritten by react, and react requests data through ajax, so it will not be redirected to server. A better method is to write the error to the page directly.

```
 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        
        app.UseExceptionHandler(builder =>
        {
            builder.Run(async context =>
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";

                var exception = context.Features.Get<IExceptionHandlerFeature>();
                if (exception != null)
                {
                    var error = new ErrorMessage()
                    {
                        Stacktrace = exception.Error.StackTrace,
                        Message = exception.Error.Message
                    };
                    var errObj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error);

                    await context.Response.WriteAsync(errObj).ConfigureAwait(false);
                }
            });
        });
        
       //...
    }
```

Class

```
public class ErrorMessage
{
    public string Stacktrace { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

If you can not view the error message, open the browser's console, click the server error.

[image]

Then, it will navigate to the error code.

[image]

Comment: @Matthew Miller, could accept this answer, which can help more people.